# What is best representation for mongo _id field in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Mongodb `_id` field is defined as:

```
ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

what would be most efficient representation of this field in postgresql?

Comment: A UUID seems like a good fit - or if you don't need all that additional "baggage", just use a integer column populated through a sequence

Comment: Use BSON when you need BSON: https://github.com/maciekgajewski/postgresbson

Comment: I usually use `char(24)` and store the hex representation of the ObjectId then add a CHECK constraint to ensure it has the proper format. As far as "efficient" goes, efficient in what sense? Speed? Space? Programmer time? Reducing head count? I find that the 24 character hex representation is the easiest and friendliest format to go to and from. You might not be able to easily use postgresbson depending on what you're using to interface with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are you looking to create ids in PostGres following the MongoDB semantics?
https://gist.github.com/jamarparris/6100413

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used `char(24)` with a constraint `CHECK decode(mongo_id::text, 'hex'::text) > '\x30'::bytea`. While this constraint doesn't check the sanity of the ObjectId, it allows only valid format to be stored. This stores the ObjectId in plain text, which keeps the values easily readable.

Other option could be to use `bytea` type for the column, and input the data as `"\xOBJECT_ID"` where `\x` transforms text form of OBJECT_ID to a byte array. This consumes less space than `char(24)` (might be relevant if you have millions of rows), but accessing the values in a non-binary format requires using eg. `encode(mongo_id::bytea, 'hex')` (might be burdensome).

Also some platforms such as RedShift might have problems with the `bytea` data type.

If you need an easy access to the metadata in the ObjectId, you could parse and store it separately (eg. in a `jsonb` column or a separate column for each relevant attribute). Possibly the "created at" part of the metadata is the only interesting attribute.